# Twitter4j with a twitter4j.properties file

Tags: twitter4j

I'm trying to post to Twitter using Twitter4j and putting my OAuth credentials in a `twitter4j.properties` file as per the documentation on http://twitter4j.org.

However I'm stuck as to properly post to Twitter using the credentials this file, as I can only find examples that use `ConfigurationBuilder` and there's no clear example on which methods to use when the credentials are all stored in a `twitter4j.properties` file.

I've tried both:

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
twitter.updateStatus("My status");
```

and

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.updateStatus("My status");
```

both of which give me an "Authentication credentials are missing" error.

I've looked at the examples that come with Twitter4j and they involve getting the Access Tokens through a URL callback, which I really don't need as I already have obtained all the credentials from https://apps.twitter.com/

I realise that I could just use the `new ConfigurationBuilder()` method but this forces me to copy and paste the keys into each of my classes which is time consuming and looks clunky. What's the proper way to set credentials from the `twitter4j.properties` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I understand now that the `twitter4j.properties` file had to be placed in the `WEB-INF` folder in my case, as I am running a Google App Engine servlet.

The wording on http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html is vague and ambiguous, as it simply states that the file `twitter4j.properties` should be placed in "either the current directory or root of the classpath directory". In my case I was originally placing it in the same directory as my other source files, which meant that Twitter4J couldn't find it ostensibly because it only searched in the root of the classpath directory, which I am going to assume in my case it's `WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just place it in **src/main/resources/twitter4j.properties** and then use it:

```
    //scala
    val tweet4u = TwitterFactory.getSingleton()
    tweet4u.updateStatus("Tes1t")
```